# Set theory question on the definition of surjection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have just picked up a book on set theory for the first time. I am having trouble understanding what the second $y$ is doing in this definition for surjection.

> $\forall \, y \in B, \, \, \exists \, x  \in A y = f(x)$

all of $y$ is an element of $B$, there exists $x$ as an element of $A ... =$ function image

Where ... fill in the blank!

Is it $A y$? If so, what exactly does this mean for the definition?

Comment: that should read in english: for any y in the set B, we can find some x in A (the pre image of f) such that we can hit that y with x using our function f

Comment: Showing once again that an author that would use no delimiters between quantifiers and their scope would also steal sheep....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a blank (or colon or comma) missing: A function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is surjective, if for every element $y \in B$, there is some $x \in A$ such that the value of $f$ at the point $x$ is equal to $y$, i.e. $f(x)=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a comma is missing to add clarity:

$$\forall\,y\in B\;\exists\,x\in A\,,\,\,y=f(x).$$

And in english: for all $\;y\in B\;$ there exists $\;x\in A\;$ such that $\;y=f(x)\;$.